# Как получить результат выполнения команды cmd в скрипте python?

Tags: python

Например мои попытки  `cmd path` -
Получается не то. Или аргумент передаю некорректно или вывод читаю некорректно.

```
import subprocess

    args = ["cmd", "path"]
    process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if output == b'':
            break
        if output:
            print(output.strip().decode('cp866'))
```

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 

path_list = (os.environ['path']).split(';')
for i in path_list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: А для другого примера придётся другой скрипт писать?